# Selecting single value from two columns using where

Tags: mysql

sorry, if this question is silly or naive as i am new to mysql.

My table structure:

```
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| SampleTime | ClosePrice  | OpenPrice    |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| 09:30:00   |     2010.23 |      2010.83 |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| 09:31:00   |     2009.53 |      2009.65 |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| 09:32:00   |     2010.63 |      2010.66 |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| 15:59:00   |     2010.76 |      2009.76 |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
```

I want to have OpenPrice where SampleTime is 09:30:00 and ClosePrice where SampleTime is 15:59:00.

I wrote a query but it is not working:

```
SELECT 
    OpenPrice,
    ClosePrice 
FROM Prices 
WHERE SampleTime = '09:30:00' 
    and SampleTime ='15:59:00'
```

Comment: You've got a few answers here with people more or less taking wild guesses about what kind of output you want.  It's always beneficial to provide an example of your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT 
 MAX(case when SampleTime='09:30:00' then OpenPrice end) OpenPrice,
 MAX(case when SampleTime='15:59:00' then ClosePrice end) ClosePrice
FROM Prices
```

Comment: Just noticed that this looks like a repetition of @fa06's answer. It seems we had the same thought at the same time ...

Comment: but my answer has been posted 8 min before your..does not matter..people have same thoughts in same time :)

Comment: I am a slow typer ... especially on my smartphone. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using between & and

```
SELECT OpenPrice,ClosePrice FROM Prices WHERE SampleTime between '09:30:00' and '15:59:00'
```

Or from your question is seems like

```
select min(case when SampleTime='09:30:00' then openprice end) as openprice,
min(case when SampleTime='15:59:00' then closeprice end) as closeprice  from prices
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a Union:

```
SELECT OpenPrice as Price FROM Prices WHERE SampleTime = '09:30:00'
union
Select ClosePrice as Price from Prices where SampleTime ='15:59:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
SELECT a.OpenPrice, b.ClosePrice FROM Prices AS a, Prices AS b WHERE a.SampleTime='09:30:00' AND b.SampleTime='15:59:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get these in one row you can simply select each cell you want in it's own subquery like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT OpenPrice FROM Prices WHERE SampleTime = '09:30:00') AS OpenPrice,
    (SELECT ClosePrice FROM Prices WHERE SampleTime ='15:59:00') AS ClosePrice
```

And as a side note, you should definitely have an index on `SampleTime` for performance sake.